# Angular conditions within a table

Tags: angularjs, html, angular

I would like to use multiple conditions within a table but can't figure out how to do it.

```
table
    tbody
        div(*ngFor='let item of list')
            div(*ngIf='item.type=="cover"')
                tr(*ngIf='displayElements[(item.invoice.date | date:"MM-yy")]')
                    td {{ item.name }}
                    td {{ item._id }}
            div(*ngIf='item.type=="invoice"')
                tr(*ngIf='displayElements[(item.date | date:"MM-yy")]')
                    td {{ item.name }}
                    td {{ item._id }}
```

As you can see, the table is not valid html as it has two `div` inside. How can I solve this issue (note that I'm using Angular 2)?

Comment: Why can't you do all the conditions on the `tr` node? Also, you can multiple the `tbody` node if you have to.

Comment: @MoshFeu Because Angular2 doesn't let me check a non-existant variable. For example if `item.invoice` doesn't exist (which is the case when `item.type` is equal to `invoice`, angular will return an error when it will check `item.invoice.date`)

Comment: What do you mean by " doesn't let me check a non-existant variable."? Maybe `item.invoice?.date` is what you want?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I didn't know I could use a question mark, thanks for the info. However, sometimes item is an array and I have to check: `item[0].invoice.date`. How would you do this one then?

Comment: You can use the `?` before each `.` You can **not** use it before `[]`. `?.` doesn't check the properties coming afterwards if the part before it is `null`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Then how would you solve this issue? Is there any "invisible" tag I could use inside a table?

Comment: You can use the canonical way of `ngIf` and `ngFor` like `<template [ngIf]="...">...</template>`. The `<template>` tag is only used internally by Angular and never added to the DOM. I guess I don't really understand what your actual problem is but maybe this is what you were looking for anyway. `<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="list">...</template>` is the canonical form of `ngFor`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120600/discussion-between-ncohen-and-gunter-zochbauer).